# Http Error in J2ME app

Tags: http, java-me

I am trying to make an Http connection in a J2ME application.

Problem is that it is running fine in the emulator; but in a mobile, it is showing IO exception- Error in Http Operation.

Can anyone tell me what prompts this kind of error.
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
Seems like it was a very stupid mistake on my part...I had'nt written the Connection code within a thread.
Small change solved the problem. Just rewrote the Connection part within run() of thread.

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of possible causes:

- Incorrect network settings
- No mobile reception
- No credit on PAYG
- URL inaccessible through mobile operator's walled garden

Which API call in particular generates the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget the midlet permissions in the Jad file too. They too may cause an error.